# syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax

```
./csf_install.sh: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `CHECK_distro'
./csf_install.sh: line 30: `CHECK_distro()'
```

My code:

```
    if [ "$(whoami &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ] && [ "$(id -un &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ] ; then
        $BIN_ECHO " must be root to run this script "
        exit 1
    else
        $BIN_ECHO -e " permission check passed "
    fi
    CHECK_architecture()
    CHECK_distro()
...
CHECK_architecture()
{
    architecture=`uname -m`
    if [ "$architecture" != "x86_64" ] && [ "$architecture" != "ia64" ]; then
        architecture="x86"
    else
        architecture="x86_64"
    fi
}

CHECK_distro()
{
    DISTRO="";
    if [ `uname -r | egrep '(6.2-RELEASE|6.1-RELEASE|5.5-RELEASE|6.1-STABLE|5.4-RELEASE|6.0-RELEASE|5.3-RELEASE|4.10-RELEASE|4.11-RELEASE)'` ]; then
        DISTRO="FreeBSD";
        $BIN_ECHO " System is running FreeBSD"
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ];  then
           $BIN_ECHO " System is running Debian Linux"
           DISTRO=DEBIAN;
    elif [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
           $BIN_ECHO " System is running SuSE Linux"
           DISTRO=SUSE;
    elif [ -f /etc/fedora-release ]; then
           $BIN_ECHO " System is running Fedora Linux"
           DISTRO=FEDORA;
    elif [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
           $BIN_ECHO " System is running Red Hat Linux"
           DISTRO=REDHAT;
    else
        $BIN_ECHO -e " no supported distribution found running "
    exit 1
fi
}
```

Is it that my check code is wrong? Or is it how I am doing my functions? Do the functions need to come first?

ALSO

Is there a better way to check and set distribution of operating systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call functions, leave off the `()` (you call them like any other shell command):

```
CHECK_architecture
CHECK_distro
```

You will probably also want to declare the functions before using them to avoid any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use parentheses when you invoke a function, and define functions before you call them.

eg:

```
foo() { # define foo; }
foo 1 2 3 # call foo with 3 arguments
```